# no operator "==" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operands

I don't know what is causing this, but i think it has something to do with the 
function "password_checker" ??

here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string password_checker();

int main()
{
string password;
cout << "please enter your password: " << endl;
cin >> password;
if (password == password_checker)
{
    cout << "Access granted" << endl;
}
else if (password == password_checker)
{
    cout << "Access denied" << endl;
}
Sleep(15000);
return 0;
}   

string password_checker()
{
string password = "123456";
return password;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
password == password_checker
```

That's trying to call `operator==` on a string and a function pointer. You need to call the function so you get a string:

```
password == password_checker()
```

Answer (score 3):

You should call the function: `password_checker()`.

And in `else if` part it should be not equals, `!=`, or just `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Compiler thinks, that in line 
`if (password == password_checker)`
you are trying to see if password variable and password_checker function are the same. You have to call that function: `password_checker()`.